# Why lazy load integer property result doesn't match Integer instance

Tags: ruby

I have the argument value which may be lazy load property [actually it's got from BatchLoader library](https://github.com/exAspArk/batch-loader) of Integer. The value behaves a bit strange when using case-expression. At convenience, Integer === (lose comparison) operator the results are,

```
[11] pry(ActiveJob::Arguments)> Integer === argument.to_i
=> true
[12] pry(ActiveJob::Arguments)> Integer === argument
=> false
[13] pry(ActiveJob::Arguments)> argument.is_a?(Integer)
=> true
[14] pry(ActiveJob::Arguments)> argument.class.name
=> "Integer"
```

Why is the second result false and is there a way to check where the argument is derived from？

Comment: Sometimes Ruby classes employ a bit of stealth and deception, where `class` is actually a delegated method. It's worth checking if `argument.methods - Integer.instance_methods` has anything notable in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tadman describes, our argument variable's methods is overwrited by the batch-loader library and it causes failure of comparison. We can check it by @tadman's solution.　Thank you for that.